NewConnection() error while using rabbitmq in Kotlin
I am just trying to print "Hello World" using rabbitmq but I have a NewConnection() error. Rabbitmq has no tutorial for kotlin developers and i am using java tutorial for kotlin with changing syntax. Here is my codes and the error message:
package com.example.rabbitmq

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory

fun main() {
    val factory = ConnectionFactory()
    factory.host = "localhost"  // RabbitMQ sunucusunun IP adresi veya hostname
    factory.port = 5672  // RabbitMQ sunucusunun portu
    factory.username = "guest"  // RabbitMQ kullanıcı adı
    factory.password = "guest"  // RabbitMQ şifresi

    try {
        val connection = factory.newConnection()
        val channel = connection.createChannel()
        println("Connection Success!")
        channel.close()
        connection.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}





implementation("com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.21.0")
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0")
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0")

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:61)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:69)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:165)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1242)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1198)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1156)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1321)
    at com.example.rabbitmq.RabbitKt.main(rabbit.kt:13)
    at com.example.rabbitmq.RabbitKt.main(rabbit.kt)

Process finished with exit code 0


Looks like the server refuses the connection. Is it set up properly? Can other apps access it on that port?
